# Angular ngx-countdown Remove Chinese characters and show only seconds

Tags: angular

I'm using `ngx-countdown` npm module to show a countdown timer on my template, and want to display only the seconds and strip off the hours, minutes, and the Chinese characters that showed up. How can I do this?

```
<div id="snackbar" class="show">
  <countdown [config]="{leftTime: 30}"></countdown>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've already found the answer. Just add `$!s!` which specifically means seconds.

```
<div id="snackbar" class="show">
  <countdown [config]="{leftTime: 30}">$!s!</countdown>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to configure it globally, just add the code in module.ts file ;

```
function countdownConfigFactory(): Config {
return { template: `$!h!:$!m!:$!s!` };
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ CountdownModule ],
  providers: [
  { provide: CountdownConfig, useFactory: countdownConfigFactory }
  ],
})
export class AppDemoModule {}
```